# Element '<xpath expr="//head/link[last()]">' cannot be located in parent view every time trying to extend portal.frontend_layout in Odoo 14

Tags: xml, xpath, frontend, odoo, odoo-14

In Odoo 14, I'm trying to add some templates that inherits `portal.frontend_layout`. But it's throwing 'Element `<xpath expr="//head/link[last()]">` cannot be located in parent view' error.

The `portal.frontend_layout` template inherits `web.frontend_layout`, where I can see that `//head/link[last()]` code is there & the inherited `web.layout` DOES have `link` inside `head` tag.

Is it an issue on the base code? or something wrong in my inherited view?

This is my sample code:

```
<template id="website_menu_header_customized" 
        inherit_id="portal.frontend_layout" 
        name="Header Language Link">
....
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have `portal` mentioned as a dependency inside your manifest file.

You could also try replacing `portal` with `web` directly.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've already added that. it's pointing to the base templates. I'm confused what's happening now.

Comment: Then try replacing `portal` with `web`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to inherit **web.frontend_layout** instead of **portal.frontend_layout**
because **portal.frontend_layout** doesn't have any head tag.

*You can not directly use XPath for the template's parent template.*